# Weird default_popup behavior

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am developing an extension that uses the default_popup, defined in the manifest (V3) as:

```
"action": {
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
```

to display a form. The form is populated with data received in the response from a sendMessage() call to the background service worker each time the extension is clicked. The data gets saved back to the service worker when any part of the form data changes, via listeners.

Everything appears to work great. I can click on the extension icon to open the popup, fill out the form, close the popup by clicking the extension icon again. Another click to open it back up and the form data is displayed just as expected.

However, if I close the popup and wait a couple of minutes before clicking the extension icon again, all of the form data is gone. But not really. If I click the extension icon two more times (i.e. once to close and again to open), the data magically reappears.

Now here's the weird part. If I open the debug console view for the background service worker, and leave it open, the form data is correctly displayed every time I click the extension to open the popup, no matter how long it has been since I closed it. It's driving me nuts!

I realize I haven't provided a whole lot of detail, but I would greatly appreciate any ideas as to why everything seems to work perfectly if the debug console for the background service worker is left open while using the extension.

Answer (score 1):

When devtools is not attached to the service worker, it lives for 30 seconds (in Chrome) since the last event such as a message, so you need to maintain the data in storage ([example](/a/73090402)) or force the worker to run while the popup is open ([example](/a/66618269)).

A better option in this case would be to get rid of the service worker (it consumes memory and CPU) and just use  `chrome.storage.local` in the popup directly to read/save the data.